# Node route function does nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm writing a simple app, which fetches some geocoding data from Google Maps Geocoding API. I'm trying to get this data for an array of addresses (in strings) using node-geocoder ([this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder)) inside an async.each() (from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)) function:

```
async.each(entries, function(entry, callback) {

    geocoder.geocode(entry.address, function(err, res) {
        resultCheck.push(res);
        var point = {
            address: entry.address,
            coordinates: {
                    latitude: res.latitude,
                    longtitude: res.longtitude
            }
        };
        pointSet.points.push(point);
        callback();
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) { errorArray.push(err); }
    });
});
```

Tests show that the async function processes every member of the array, yet the geocode function does nothing (resultCheck and errorArray are broadcasted in requests response).

Being an almost total JavaScript noob I'd also like to ask - is this approach any close to correct?

Any insights would be welcome, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Seems that the async function is not waiting for the GM API's response, got to work on that, will post if I overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issues in your code, with following assumptions

1. you use [google maps api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)
2. and use this [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module

the code should be something like this, note the signature of both [geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#methods_89) and [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

```
async.each(entries, function (entry, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode(entry.address, function (result, status) {
        resultCheck.push(result);
        var point = {
            address: entry.address,
            coordinates: {
                latitude: result.latitude,
                longtitude: result.longtitude
            }
        };
        pointSet.points.push(point);
        callback();
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        errorArray.push(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yet the updated app works exactly the same - both resultCheck and errorArray end up empty. As for your assumptions - you were correct the async package, and as for GM API, I'm not using the JavaScript API, I'm trying to connect to (I asume) the [HTTP one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) via the npm node-geocoder package. I've updated my question accordingly.